# QLinearGradient pyqt5 doesn't working with QLabel

Tags: pyqt5, gradient, linear-gradients, qtstylesheets, qlabel

In qt designer creating QLabel and set styleSheet:

```
font: bold 50px;
color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(13, 115, 119, 255), stop:1 rgba(78, 204, 163, 255));
```

But this code gives me the result: all text with one color, not with gradient
[image]

I want the gradient to be described in styleSheet.
Only text color or font color, I don't want to have QLabel with background-color gradient

My gradient:
[image]

Comment: There's a bug when setting a gradient for the `color` stylesheet property. It uses logical space as the coordinate mode instead of Object Bounding Mode. Set `x2` to the width of the text instead, e.g. `x2:230`.

Comment: I solved this problem with your help. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @FineMan While the comment from alec gives insights about the possible problem, it doesn't *really* solve the problem, especially considering that widgets shouldn't have absolute sizes (consider issues related to font scaling or HighDPI screens): using a hardcoded value might as well give very different and unexpected results on various devices. That said, I cannot reproduce the issue (probably because I don't use any of the above features), but if that visual appearance is that important, you should consider to use a subclass and implement your own painting using the QTextDocument API.

Comment: @alec I'm not able to reproduce the problem, but I found some (possibly) related issues ([12542](//bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-12542) and the incredibly old [2221](//bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-2221)). Are you referring to those? Do you have other references?

Comment: @musicamante I wasn't referring to any source it's just something I discovered awhile ago. 12542 describes it exactly. I can still reproduce on both windows and mac in PyQt5.

Comment: @alec Thanks. Sorry for the late reply but I only got time to carefully dig more into this right now. Can you please check if my answer is valid?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [alec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9435771/alec) in comments, it's a known and still unresolved bug.

It seems to affect only certain styles: I cannot reproduce it with Oxygen and Breeze, but I can with Fusion and Windows, which probably means that it's caused by the default implementation of [`QStyle.drawItemText()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#drawItemText) and the way the QStyleSheetStyle provides parameters to that function (specifically, the palette).

I'll eventually check further more into this, but right now it seems that a possible workaround is to reset the label palette whenever the style sheet affects the label (either by using the parent or the application).

Note that this is a conceptually *bad* workaround, more like a "brute force" one; remember that, as the [documentation warns](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#palette-prop), we shall not use `setPalette()` along with style sheets.

Still, considering the partial simplicity of QLabel, we can overrule that aspect, as long as it works (and the bug is finally, hopefully fixed).

The simple solution is to use a subclass, override its [`changeEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#changeEvent) and check for `PaletteChange` changes, then reset the palette based on the parent or the whole application. Note that since we are altering *again* the palette, we need a basic check in order to avoid recursion:

```py
class FixLabel(QLabel):
    _recursiveCheck = False
    def changeEvent(self, event):
        super().changeEvent(event)
        if event.type() == event.PaletteChange and not self._recursiveCheck:
            self._recursiveCheck = True
            self.setPalette(
                (self.parent() or QApplication.instance()).palette())
            self._recursiveCheck = False
```

This can obviously be done even for Designer using promoted widgets, or by installing an event filter for the QApplication.

In that case, we could eventually check for the `WA_StyleSheetTarget` attribute, which tells us if the label actually uses style sheets:

```py
class FixLabelFilter(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        app = QApplication.instance()
        super().__init__(app)
        self.recursiveSet = set()
        app.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if (
            isinstance(obj, QLabel) 
            and event.type() == event.PaletteChange
            and obj not in self.recursiveSet
            and obj.testAttribute(Qt.WA_StyleSheetTarget)
        ):
            self.recursiveSet.add(obj)
            obj.setPalette(
                (self.parent() or QApplication.instance()).palette()
            )
            self.recursiveSet.remove(obj)
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

...

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
FixLabelFilter()

...
```

Note that there is no need to create a reference for the `FixLabelFilter` instance, as the parent argument of the `super().__init__()` will change the ownership to the application, thus making it persistent.

Comment: Can confirm it works